# Multiple jar version and reading classes from particular jar

Tags: java, jar

There is a present application which read a very old version of Apache common io version 1.2 . We are releasing a few new updates using the latest 2.3 after a very long time and we want to run new codes only using the latest commons IO jar file. 
How i can handle this issue so that new codes reads only from the latest common IO jar and older from old version. ( in short don't touch anything which is running )

Searching online i have realized that i need to load classes but slightly confused whether i should do UrlClassLoader or ClassLoader , If class loading is the right path then how can i read all the  classes  ,since classes inside have dependency with each other, so that if i call the main class to run my codes it executes without worrying about dependency or calling each class

Please suggest ? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Class loaders are definitely part of the solution, but it is very tricky to implement this yourself. Try using OSGi which is going to do this for you if you configure it properly.

Comment: Thank you will look into OSGi

Answer (score 0):

You can use an OSGi framework and run both Apache common io libraries beside each other. 
You can then control which of your bundles uses which apache library bundle by exporting and respectively importing the packages with a specific version.

You will have in the lib bundle: 
Export-Package: com.acme.foo;version="1.24"

and in the bundle using it:

Import-Package: com.acme.foo;version="[1.23, 2.0)"

Since in OSGi every bundle has its own separate classloader, the loading of all correct subpackages and classes will be handled automatically and there will be no conflicts.

You can check for example [these instructions and demos for writing OSGi bundles](http://dz.prosyst.com/pdoc/mBS_SDK/um/runtime/osgi/docs/index.html) - to run them use [mBedded Server](http://www.prosyst.com/index.php/de/html/content/97/Products-OSGi-Implementation/).